# EF Data Migrations - Schema changes successfully applied but no data seed occurring?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-migration, seeding

I have an initial create in my migrations folder alongside a subsequent migration file. When I run `Update-Database -ProjectName Data -StartUpProjectName Ui -Script` from the Package Manager Console I get the Sql script that would be executed should I actually execute `Update-Database` without the `-Script` attribute.

The Sql it generates contains all of the schema creation and modifications that I would expect it to but it doesn't include the `INSERT` statements that I would expect to be present as per my `Seed` method. I've tried deleting the database and letting everything get created again both via `Update-Database` and by setting `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` in my configuration.cs but regardless, I only get the schema generated, never the data.

I've obviously changed something I shouldn't have as data has been seeding just fine but has stopped this afternoon. Does anyone have any obvious suggestions for reasons why this might happen?

To confirm, I have the following method in my configuration.cs file which is unchanged from earlier today when seeding was taking place:

```
protected override void Seed(ContextClassHere context)
{
    // Calls to seed methods located here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I can't explain why the `Seed` method wasn't running but I've learnt a lot more about how to use `Data-Migrations` now which is a nice side-effect. I had made modifications to my model which I had scripted in a new migration file manually. It turns out I needn't have bothered as there's a tool that will do it for me, namely `Add-Migration`. Armed with this knowledge I rolled my model back to pre-modification, ran the `InitialCreate` which worked as expected with seed taking place, then ran the `Add-Migration` method which created the new migration file for me and now everything is working as expected again with the `Seed` method running every time.

I can't quite explain why the `Seed` method wasn't executing but everything is working as expected again now following the above process.